# Redirect anonymous user to login in custom module

Tags: 7, redirection, users

In a custom module, I'd like to redirect anonymous users to the login page. After a successful login the user should get to the page he intended to see.

I tried the following code. This gives me the login form, but the user is never sent to the destination page. Instead the standard user page gets displayed.

```
if (!$user->uid) {
    $dest = drupal_get_destination();
    drupal_goto('user/login', $dest['destination']);
}
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `drupal_goto('user/login', array("query" => array("destination" => $dest['destination'])))`?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize realize that it's double indexed.

Comment: You can use `drupal_get_destination()` function. `drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));`